# "Pairing" time for two Wi-Fi Direct devices

Tags: java, android, data-transfer, wifi-direct

How quick can devices with `Wi-Fi Direct` hardware connect directly to each other? Is it possible for two persons that walk by on a street at normal speed to exchange some information using `Wi-Fi Direct` devices?

Answer (score 4):

As *smiley* writes Wi-Fi Direct discovery and group formation/pairing timing/delay depends upon various factors:

- Hardware & Driver/protocol implementation
- If one of the devices is *autonomous* group owner (GO)
- If service discovery is used

I have measured the timing on two *Samsung Galaxy S III* devices and discovered the following average timing/delays for discovery+group formation:

- Autonomous GO without service discovery: **4 s**
- Autonomous GO with service discovery: **4.5 s**
- Standard group with/without service discovery: **6 s**

Normal walking speed is around *1.4 m/s*, so it should be possible to connect and exchange a small amount of data, depending on the signalling conditions.

Regarding the issue with accepting Wi-Fi Direct connections without user involvement, this is possible to do up to Android 4.3, by using the hidden method `setDialogListener` in `android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager`.

Comment: This is very useful info thanks! I did similar tests, but on some slower devices, getting an average of about 8.3 s and std deviation of 2.7s while using service advertising and discovery to initiate connection (GO advertises a service, clients discover and initiate connect to GO). I took 300 samples, could you specify how many test you have done?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the connection time would be different depending upon various factors.

Your problem, however, wouldn't be with the connection time between two devices. Instead, it would be your application's inability to accept a Wi-Fi Direct connection on behalf of the user.

This is something which several people have already pointed out in other stackoverflow questions and on the [Android Open Handset Alliance Project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30880)

Comment: Yes but if the user has custom App installed on his device then two devices can connect to each other via Wi-FI direct. We plan to have this for "offline messaging" for our InTouch Messaging application